What error correcting+detecting code to use for short bitstream messages like 24-32bits? (ReedSolomon, CRC, BCH...?)
I'm sending bit streams (messages) of data with length of 32bits.
I want to add error correcting code to these messages. For example 16 bits of "parity" bits.
As a first approach I use RS(6,4) over GF(256) - So, the data is treated as 4 bytes, and two bytes of error correcting code is added. As I understand, for this configuration of RS, one byte of entire 6-bytes message can be changed (corrupted) and RS decoding algorithm will still be able to recover original message. (If two bytes are corrupted, RS decoding will signal that unrecoverable error).
So, in theory, all 8 bits of one byte can be changed and the message still will be recovered.
But the nature of posiible errors in by scenario is that each bit can be changed with some probability.
So using RS(6,4)/GF(256) will not recover the message if only two bits will be changed in some random places, not inside the same byte.
I want to recover if ANY 5 bits are changed.
UPDATE
It seems that Reed Solomon is not suitable here, so:
Which ECC to use?
How many parity bits are required?

The data size is 32bits There is only one message that will be sent
over and over.
There is up to 15% (we can compare with 10%)
probability that each bit is flipped.
I want to be able do reliably
decode the 32bit of data as soon as possible. If the first packet
(32bit data+X bit parity) is damaged beyond recovery, the receiver
waits for the next packet (exactly the same data+parity) and retry.
But in most cases receiving first message should be enough.
Decoding can be computionally intensive.

Naive algorithm
I came up with following naive algorithm based on this answer for different question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27865713/207717

Add some CRC to the 32bit message (for example CRC-16 or CRC-24)
On the receiver side, if CRC does not match iterate all the ways that 1,2,3,4,5 bits can be flipped (this gives few millions of iterations = (48 choose 1) + (48 choose 2) + (48 choose 3) + (48 choose 4)+(48 choose 5) - I'm okay with this.

Does it makes sense? And it if so - What is the maximal number of bits I can correct for:

32bit of data + CRC-16
32bit of data + CRC-24
322bit of data + CRC-32

At some point testing N number of flipped bits will produce collisions with different valid messages. That is the N for various CRCs?
UPDATE 2
rcgldr comment pointed me in direction of BCH codes.
I ported this implementation https://www.eccpage.com/bch3.c to C# to make some tests with codeword 48bits, 24bits of data, 24 parity bits and error correcting capacity 4.
It works perfectly up to 4 errors, but with 5 errors it often makes mistakes - the error is not detected and the decoder thinks that it decoded succesfully (the line printf("Incomplete decoding: errors detected\n") is never reached).
So here is another question: As BCH are error correcting codes, does that mean that they are not able to detect errors above the correcting capacity? Or the linked implementation is flawed?
Eventually: How to achive error correcting AND detecting capacity? For example: be able to correct up to 4 errors and detect up to 7 errors, data length 24bits, decoding complexity not important.
UPDATE 3
As far I have working BCH c# code translated from here https://www.eccpage.com/bch3.c
C# version here: https://codefile.io/f/NYCxFluwzE
I still don't know how to create error correcting code that will allow correcting up to 4 errors and then, at the same time, detecting up to 7 errors for my 24bits of data + required parity bits
UPDATE 4
I used @rcgldr code to run the experiment - testing cases with more errors than error correcting capability:
https://pastecode.io/s/k319ojhb
Result matches my intuition that if the code has error correcting capability=5 and but there are 6 errors then the decoding fails (cannot decode) OR gives invalid codeword after correcting exactly 5 errors. (in fact the code, in some rare cases, recovers valid codeword after making, supposedly, 6 corrections - something that should not be possible, but I guess that are just some lucky cases?)

Is above conclusion certain? If there are 6 errors, there will always be decoding error OR exactly 6 errors corrected (towards some random codeword)?
If so, Can I use the exact same code for correcting 4 and detecting up to 6 errors? (simply treating correction of 5th error as error-detected, not corrected)? Or is there a better way?
How to adjust this code for different error cap and data lengths?

UPDATE 5 + Solution
Code from accepted answer does the trick - corrects up to 4 and detects up to 7 errors.
The only difficulty is that it uses unsigned long for storing and processing codewords - this, together with using caryless multiplication gives great performance. Performance is not an issue for  me so, for clarity, I'll probably rewrite it to use bit arrays (arrays of ints: zeros and ones) to represent codewords.

What matters is the nature of your error channel, e.g. the bit error rate and the distribution of those errors. Are the errors memoryless, or do they come in bursts? Second, what error rate do you require coming out of the decoder? Given that, you can try out lots of different codes using https://github.com/aff3ct/aff3ct .

If you want to use Reed-Solomon because, say, you already have existing code, you can interleave your messages over for example eight 48-bit packets to get much better random error performance. You would need to be able to accept the consequent delay in decoding the first message.

@MarkAdler Yes, I have existing Reed Solom code, but I'm open to use different ECC.

@MarkAdler Nature on the channel: The channel is very specific (not radio or electrical), without diving into details: I transmit the message (lets assume 24-48 bits) over and over, repeating. On the receiver I got the bitstream with some bits flipped. We can assume that no more than 15% of the bits, at random positions, can be flipped

@MarkAdler I dont understand how to interleave using Reed-Solom, could you give an example? Maybe the fact that I'm sending only one packet will make things easier?For example I want to send 24 data bits + some error correcting bits. After that I will send the same data+ecc again and again. I want to be able to reliably decode data bits on the decoder as soon as possdible, possible after receiving first data+ecc packet.

@rcgldr Maybe i'm not using the correct nomenclature. I meant that I use ReedSolomon where each symbol is one byte (0-255). This is not optimal because I habe only 3 or 4 bytes of data to send. If I add 2 parity bytes i will be recover from bit-errors only if they happen in the same byte.  What i want to achieve is, for example: having 32bits of data, add 16 parity bits (48bit message) and be able to recover if ANY 8 bits are flipped on the receiver side.

You're repeating the exact same message? Why?

Interleaving can simply be: bit 0 of message 0, bit 0 of message 1, ..., bit 0 of message 7, bit 1 of message 0, bit 1 of message 1, ..., ..., bit 31 of message 6, bit 31 of message 7. Then encode that with your RS code.

@MarkAdler The truth is I have only one message to transmit (this is kind of ID) so I dan't have more messages to interleave. I can duplicate each bit of my message, but still I dont understand how this help for my problem with RS - if error bits are spread across different bytes of message they become unrecoverable.

@PanJanek you should really check to see if your transmission medium will support soft decoding, i.e. whether you can output a confidence score for each bit. If so, turbo codes will generally provide much better performance.

@nneonneo transmission medium in fact will produce confidence for each bit. Each bit has confidence > 0.5 and <=1.0 (confidence less than 0.5 means that the other bit value has confidence > 0.5)

I updated my answer. The code is now C#, using the intrinsic for pclmulqdq, corrects up to 4 bits in error, detects up to 7 bits in error.  30 bits data, 33 bits parity.

@rcgldr Thank you again! Before noticing your updated C# code I managed to run the C code in VS (works perfectly!) and make some experiments that lead me to, somehow theoretical, question in my updated OP.

Performance is mostly an issue when trying to prove the code can handle all 628,882,431 combination of 63 bits with 1 to 7 errors.

@rcgldr I posted follow up question about possibility of using confidence levels for received bits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79172530/what-error-correcting-code-to-use-for-short-messages-over-noisy-channel-using-co


in some rare cases, the code recovers a valid codeword with more errors than expected

The Berlekamp Massey decoder can sometimes generate polynomials of greater degree than expected. This could be prevented with a check on polynomial size, but if the  unexpected polynomial is wrong, it will get caught when the roots are generated by Poly2Root(). If using a shortened codeword (less than 63 bits in this case), then the roots would be checked to see if any of them correspond to out of range indexes, also preventing mis-correction.
8 syndromes should only be good for 4 errors, but some 5, 6, 7 bit errors will be corrected (7 is very rare).
Sugiyama extended Euclid decoder doesn't generate polynomials of greater degree than expected.

Example Visual Studio 2022 C# code using X86 carryless multiply intrinsic for PCLMULQDQ: Pclmulqdq.CarrylessMultiply(). 30 bits data, 33 bits parity. Corrects 1 to 4 bit errors and detects 5 to 7 bit errors, using 11 syndromes for encoding and detection, and 8 of the syndromes for correction. The correction uses Berlekamp Massey decoder or if #define EEUCLID uses Sugiyama extended Euclid decoder. After a correction, the encoding logic ReEncode() is used to check if the codeword is valid rather than regenerating and checking 11 syndromes. The code tests all 628,882,431 combinations of 1 to 7 bits out of 63 bits. This takes about 17 minutes on my lap top. Displays * every 1,048,576 loops as a progress indicator, about 600 *.
//      bch6347.cs        63 bit codeword, GF(2^6)
//                        correct 4 bits, detect 7 bits
//                        2024NOV04 14:50

// if EEUCLID defined use Sugiyama extended Euclid decoder
// else use Berlekamp Massey decoder
//#define EEUCLID

using System.Runtime.Intrinsics;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86;
using System.Numerics;
using static System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSType;
using System;

namespace xcs
{
#if EEUCLID
    public class EUCLID
    {
        public byte size;
        public byte indx;
        public byte[]  data;
        public EUCLID() => this.data = new byte[62];
    }
#endif

    public class VECTOR
    {
        public byte size;
        public byte[] data;
        public VECTOR() => this.data = new byte[31];
    }
    public class Program
    {
        const byte POLY = 0x43;                     // GF(2^6) = x^6 + x + 1
        const byte ALPHA = 0x02;
        const byte NSYN = 11;
        const byte NFIX = 8;
        static byte[] vZeroes = new byte[32];       // zeroes
        static byte[] exp64 = new byte[128];        // exp64 table
        static byte[] log64 = new byte[64];         // log64 table
        static byte[] minplyf = new byte[128];      // minimum polynomial flags
        static byte[] minply = new byte[64];        // minimum polynomials
        static byte mincnt;                         // # of minimum polymials
        static Vector128<ulong> poly;               // generator poly
        static Vector128<ulong> invpoly;            // 2^64 / POLY
        static Vector128<ulong> msg;                // message
        static Vector128<ulong> par;                // parities
        static ulong msgorg;                        // original message
        static ulong msgenc;                        // encoded message
        static ulong msgerr;                        // received message
        static ulong msgfix;                        // fixed message
        static VECTOR vSyndromes = new VECTOR();    // syndromes
#if EEUCLID
        static EUCLID ED = new EUCLID();            // for GenpErrors EE
        static EUCLID ER = new EUCLID();
        static EUCLID ET = new EUCLID();
#else
        static VECTOR vB = new VECTOR();            // for GenpErrors BM
        static VECTOR vC = new VECTOR();
        static VECTOR vT = new VECTOR();
        static VECTOR vBx = new VECTOR();
#endif
        static VECTOR pErrors = new VECTOR();       // error locator polynomial
        static VECTOR vLocators = new VECTOR();     // locators
        static VECTOR vOffsets = new VECTOR();      // offsets

        static byte GFAdd(byte b0, byte b1) /* add */
        {
            return (byte)(b0^b1);
        }

        static byte GFSub(byte b0, byte b1) /* subtract */
        {
            return (byte)(b0^b1);
        }

        static byte GFMpy(byte b0, byte b1) /* multiply */
        {
        int m2;
            if(0 == b0 || 0 == b1)
                return 0;
            m2 = (int)log64[b0]+(int)log64[b1];
            return exp64[m2];
        }

        static byte GFDiv(byte b0, byte b1) /* divide */
        {
        int m2;
            if(0 == b0)
                return 0;
            m2 = (int)log64[b0]+63-(int)log64[b1];
            return exp64[m2];
        }

        static byte GFPwr(byte b0, byte b1)
        {
            if(b1 == 0)
                return 1;
            if(b0 == 0)
                return 0;
            return exp64[(byte)((log64[b0]*(uint)b1)%63)];
        }

        static byte GFMpy0(byte b0, byte b1)
        {
            byte i;
            byte product;
                product = 0;
                for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
                    product <<= 1;
                    if(0x40 == (product & 0x40))
                        product ^= POLY;
                    if(0x20 == (b0 & 0x20u))
                        product ^= b1;
                    b0 <<= 1;}
                return product;
        }

        static void InitGF()
        {
            int i;
            byte b = 1;
            for(i = 0; i < 128; i++){
                exp64[i] = b;
                b = GFMpy0(b, ALPHA);
            }
            log64[0] = 0xff;
            for(i = 0; i < 63; i++){
                log64[exp64[i]] = (byte) i;}
        }

        static int GenPoly()
        {
        ulong M;
        ulong N;
        ulong Q;
        int x;
        byte mpoly;                     /* test polynomial */
        byte sum;                       /* sum, looking for zeroes */
        byte apwr;                      /* alpha to power */
        byte i,j;

            /* find minimum and non-duplicate polynomials for m[1] -> m[NSYN] */
            i = 0;
            do{
                apwr = GFPwr(ALPHA,++i);
                for(mpoly = 0x02; mpoly <= 0x7f ; mpoly++){
                    sum = 0;
                    for(j = 0; j <= 6; j++){
                        if(0 != (mpoly&(1<<j)))
                            sum ^= GFPwr(apwr,j);
                    }
                    if(sum == 0){
                        if(minplyf[mpoly] != 0)
                            continue;
                        minplyf[mpoly] = 1;
                        minply[mincnt] = mpoly;
                        mincnt += 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }while(i < NSYN);

            poly = Vector128.Create((ulong)(minply[0]), 0x0000000000000000ul);
            for(i = 1; i < mincnt; i++){
                poly = Vector128.Create((ulong)(minply[i]), poly.GetElement<ulong>(0));
                poly = Pclmulqdq.CarrylessMultiply(poly, poly, 0x01);
            }

            // generate 2^64 / poly
            x = 63-BitOperations.LeadingZeroCount(poly.GetElement<ulong>(0));
            M = 1ul<<x;
            N = M>>1;
            Q = 0x0ul;
            for(i = 0; i < 65-x; i++){
                N <<= 1;
                Q <<= 1;
                if(0 != (N&M)){
                    Q |= 1;
                    N ^= (poly.GetElement<ulong>(0));
                }
            }
            invpoly = Vector128.Create(Q, 0x0000000000000000ul);
            return 63-BitOperations.LeadingZeroCount(poly.GetElement<ulong>(0));
        }

        static void Encode()
        {
            par = Pclmulqdq.CarrylessMultiply(msg, invpoly, 0x00);  // par[1] = quotient
            par = Pclmulqdq.CarrylessMultiply(par, poly, 0x01);     // par[0] = product
            par ^= msg;                                             // par[0] = remainder
            msg ^= par;                                             // msg[0] = encoded message
        }

        static int ReEncode()
        {
            par = Pclmulqdq.CarrylessMultiply(msg, invpoly, 0x00);  // par[1] = quotient
            par = Pclmulqdq.CarrylessMultiply(par, poly, 0x01);     // par[0] = product
            par ^= msg;                                             // par[0] = remainder
            if(0ul == par.GetElement<ulong>(0))
                return 0;
            return 1;
        }

        static void GenSyndromes()
        {
            ulong M;
            byte x;
            byte i, ap, s;
            vSyndromes.size = NFIX;
            for (i = 0; i < NFIX; i++)
            {
                M = msg.GetElement<ulong>(0);
                ap = GFPwr(ALPHA, (byte)(i+1));
                s = 0;
                while (0 != M)
                {
                    x = (byte)(63 - BitOperations.LeadingZeroCount(M));
                    M ^= 1ul << x;
                    s ^= GFPwr(ap, x);
                }
                vSyndromes.data[i] = s;
            }
        }

        static int Poly2Root(ref VECTOR vDst, ref VECTOR pSrc)
        {
            byte bLcr;                          // current locator
            byte bSum;                          // current sum
            byte bV;                            // index to pVDst
            byte i, j;

            vDst.size = (byte)(pSrc.size-1);
            if (vDst.size == 0)
                return 0;

            bV = 0;
            bLcr = 1;
            for (j = 0; j < 63; j++){
                bSum = 0;                       // sum up terms
                for (i = 0; i < pSrc.size; i++){
                    bSum = GFMpy(bSum, bLcr);
                    bSum = GFAdd(bSum, pSrc.data[i]);}

                if (0 == bSum){                 // if a root
                    if (bV == vDst.size){       //   exit if too many roots
                        return 1;}
                    vDst.data[bV] = bLcr;       //    add locator */
                    bV++;}

                bLcr = GFMpy(bLcr, ALPHA);}     // set up next higher alpha

            if (bV != vDst.size)                // exit if not enough roots
                return 1;

            return 0;
        }
#if EEUCLID
        static int GenpErrors()
        {
        // class EUCLID: left side R[] is msb first | right side A[] is lsb first (reversed)
        int     i;
        byte    bME;                            // max errors possible
        byte    bQuot;                          // quotient

        //      ED = initial ED: E0.R[-1] = x^MAXERR, E0.A[0] = 1
            ED.size = NFIX+2;
            ED.indx = NFIX+1;
            ED.data[0] = 1;
            Array.Clear(ED.data, 1, NFIX);
            ED.data[ED.indx] = 1;

        //      ER = initial ER: E1.R[0] = syndrome polynomial, E1.A[-1] = 0
            ER.size = NFIX+2;
            ER.indx = NFIX+1;
            ER.data[0] = 0;
            Array.Copy(vSyndromes.data, 0, ER.data, 1, NFIX);
            Array.Reverse(ER.data, 1, NFIX);
            ER.data[ER.indx] = 0;

        //      init bME
            bME = NFIX/2;

            //      Euclid algorithm

            while (true)
            {                                   // while degree ER.R > max errors
                while ((ER.data[0] == 0) &&     //  shift dvsr left until msb!=0
                      (ER.indx != 0))
                {                               //  or fully shifted left
                    ER.indx--;
                    Array.Copy(ER.data, 1, ER.data, 0, ER.size - 1);
                    ER.data[ER.size - 1] = 0;
                }

                if (ER.indx <= bME)
                {             // if degree ER.R[] <= bME, break
                    break;
                }

                while (true)
                {                               // while more sub-divide steps
                    if (0 != ED.data[0])        //   if ED.R[] msb!=0, update ED, ER
                    {
                        bQuot = GFDiv(ED.data[0], ER.data[0]); // bQuot = ED.R[msb]/ER.R[msb]
                        for (i = 0; i < ER.indx; i++)
                        {                       // ED.R[]=ED.R[]-Q*ER.R[]
                            ED.data[i] = GFSub(ED.data[i], GFMpy(bQuot, ER.data[i]));
                        }
                        for (i = ED.indx; i < ER.size; i++)
                        {                       // ER.A[]=ER.A[]-Q*ED.A[]
                            ER.data[i] = GFSub(ER.data[i], GFMpy(bQuot, ED.data[i]));
                        }
                    }
                    if (ED.indx == ER.indx)     //   if sub-steps done, break
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    ED.indx--;                  //   shift ED left
                    Array.Copy(ED.data, 1, ED.data, 0, ED.size - 1);
                    ED.data[ED.size - 1] = 0;
                }
                ET = ER;                        // swap ED, ER
                ER = ED;
                ED = ET;
            }

            pErrors.size = (byte)(ED.size-ED.indx); // set pErrors.size

            if((ER.indx) >= pErrors.size){      //  if degree ER too high
                goto fail0;}

            //      pErrors = ED.A[] without unreversing = Lambda reversed
            Array.Copy(ED.data, ED.indx, pErrors.data, 0, pErrors.size);

            //      Make most significant coef pErrors == 1 (divide by it)
            bQuot = pErrors.data[0];
            if(bQuot == 0){
                goto fail0;}
            for(i = 0; i < pErrors.size; i++){
                pErrors.data[i] = GFDiv(pErrors.data[i], bQuot);}

            //      Find roots of pErrors (if fail, then set for no roots)

            if(0 == Poly2Root(ref vLocators, ref pErrors)){
                return 0;}
        fail0:
            pErrors.size = 1;                   // handle no root case
            pErrors.data[0] = 1;
            vLocators.size = 0;
            return 1;
        }
#else
        static int GenpErrors()
        {
            byte i, j, n;
            byte L, m;
            byte b, d;
            byte db;

            b = 1;                              // discrepancy when L last updated
            L = 0;                              // number of errors
            m = 1;                              // # iterations since L last updated
            vB.size = 1;
            vB.data[0] = 1;
            vC.size = 1;
            vC.data[0] = 1;

            for (n = 0; n < NFIX; n++){
                if (0 != (n&1)){               // BCH only, if odd step, d == 0
                    m += 1;
                    continue;}
                d = vSyndromes.data[n];         // calculate discrepancy
                for (i = 1; i <= L; i++){
                    d = GFAdd(d, GFMpy(vC.data[(vC.size - 1) - i], vSyndromes.data[n - i]));}
                if (d == 0){                    // if 0 increment m, continue
                    m += 1;
                    continue;}
                vT.size = vC.size;              // vT = vC
                Array.Copy(vC.data, vT.data, vC.size);
                db = GFDiv(d, b);               // db = (d/b)
                vBx.size = (byte)(vB.size+m);   // Bx = x^m B
                Array.Copy(vB.data, vBx.data, vB.size);
                Array.Clear(vBx.data, vB.size,  m);
                for (i = 0; i < vBx.size; i++){ // Bx *= db
                    vBx.data[i] = GFMpy(vBx.data[i], db);}
                j = (byte)(vBx.size-vC.size);   // right shift vBx or vC
                if ((sbyte)j > 0){
                    Array.Copy(vC.data, 0, vC.data, j, vC.size);
                    Array.Clear(vC.data, 0, j);
                    vC.size += j;}
                else if ((sbyte)j < 0) {
                    j = (byte)(0-j);
                    Array.Copy(vBx.data, 0, vBx.data, j, vBx.size);
                    Array.Clear(vBx.data, 0, j);
                    vBx.size += j;}
                for (i = 0; i < vC.size; i++){  // C -= Bx
                    vC.data[i] = GFSub(vC.data[i], vBx.data[i]);}
                if (n < 2*L){                   // if L not increasing
                    m += 1;
                    continue;}
                vB.size = vT.size;              //   B = T
                Array.Copy(vT.data, vB.data, vT.size);
                L = (byte)(n+1-L);              // update L
                b = d;                          // update b
                m = 1;}                         // reset m

            pErrors.size = vC.size;             // pErrors = reversed VC
            Array.Copy(vC.data, 0, pErrors.data, 0, vC.size);
            Array.Reverse(pErrors.data, 0, vC.size);

            if (0 != Poly2Root(ref vLocators, ref pErrors)){
                pErrors.size = 1;                // handle no root case
                pErrors.data[0] = 1;
                vLocators.size = 0;
                return 1;}
            return 0;
        }
#endif

        static void GenOffsets()
        {
            byte i;
            vOffsets.size = vLocators.size;
            for (i = 0; i < vLocators.size; i++)
            {
                vOffsets.data[i] = log64[vLocators.data[i]];
            }
        }

        static void FixErrors()
        {
            byte i;
            for (i = 0; i < vOffsets.size; i++)
                msg = Vector128.Create(msg.GetElement<ulong>(0)^(1ul<<vOffsets.data[i]), 0x0000000000000000ul);
        }

        static void InitCombination(ref int[] a, int k, int n)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                a[i] = i;
            --a[k - 1];
        }

        static int NextCombination(ref int[] a, int k, int n)
        {
            int pivot = k - 1;
            while (pivot >= 0 && a[pivot] == n - k + pivot)
                --pivot;
            if (pivot == -1)
                return 0;
            ++a[pivot];
            for (int i = pivot + 1; i < k; ++i)
                a[i] = a[pivot] + i - pivot;
            return 1;
        }

        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] ptn = new int[7];             // error bit indexes
            int n;                              // number of errors to test
            int i;
            ulong c = 0ul;
            Array.Clear(vZeroes);
            InitGF();
            n = GenPoly();
            Console.WriteLine("# parity bits: {0:D}", n);
            msgorg = 0x789abcde00000000ul;      // test message
            msg = Vector128.Create(msgorg, 0x0000000000000000ul);
            Encode();
            msgenc = msg.GetElement<ulong>(0);
            for (n = 1; n <= 7; n++){           // test 1 to 7 bit error patterns
                InitCombination(ref ptn, n, 63);
                while (0 != NextCombination(ref ptn, n, 63)){
                    msgerr = msgenc;
                    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                        msgerr ^= 1ul<<ptn[i];
                    msg = Vector128.Create(msgerr, 0x0000000000000000ul);
                    msgfix = msgerr;
                    GenSyndromes();             // generate syndromes
                    if(0 == GenpErrors()){      // generate error location info
                        GenOffsets();           // convert to offsets
                        FixErrors();            // correct error bits
                        msgfix = msg.GetElement<ulong>(0);}
                    if (msgenc == msgfix)       // if fixed continue
                        continue;
                    if (n <= 4 || 0 == ReEncode()){
                        Console.WriteLine("\nfailed");
                        return 0;}
                    if((++c & 0xffffful) == 0ul)
                        Console.Write("*");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\npassed");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}


Link to C version.

There are many bitstream error correcting codes, many of which are used in various telecommunications standards. For example, low-density parity check, convolutional codes, turbo codes, etc. Many of these codes support “soft” decoding where the certainty level of each bit can be used to perform maximum-likelihood decoding, increasing the probability of finding the right codeword.
Any of those would be more suitable for your application. Many of these codes sport highly configurable rates for differing levels of robustness, allowing you to precisely choose how much error correction to add based on the quality of your transmission medium.

Thanks for pointing out that Reed Solomon is not suitable for my scenario. Which ecc would you recommend assuming: about 50% increase in message size is acceptable, data size around 32bits, I want to be able to correct some number of corrupted bits, performance (speed) of computation is not improtant. Additionally I'm goint to transmit the message over and over so I need some preamble to mark boundary of the message, there is no clock to synchronize.

What medium are you transmitting over? Wireless? Have you considered using an existing protocol, like LoRA, rather than rolling your own? Anyway, any 2/3-rate code will do the trick for you, although it won't save you from e.g. missing your preamble.

I'm not transmitting over radio. I'm transmitting message in audio/video stream (not detectable for eyes/ears) and want to retrieve the message from audio/video recording/restream, of the original content. After extracting the message bits from the (possible degradated) recording I expect that some bits will be changed. 2/3 rate would be ideal but I have trouble finding reference implementation of RSC or turbo code. I think I can omit preamble if I will search the bitstream for repeating pattern (tolerating some number of flipped bits) of the known length as the message will be repeated.

What language are you using? There are many implementations if you search around, although I can’t vouch for any specifically.

What kind of 2/3 rate code can detect and correct a 15% bit error rate, that's more than a max of 1 bad bit per 7 bits.

I didn’t say that a 2/3 rate code would correct 15% error. OP said “I want to be able to correct some number of corrupted bits” in his comment. Also, keep in mind that, if soft decoding is used, the relevant parameter is the SNR-BER curve rather than an absolute number of tolerable bit errors.

@rcgldr if more parity bits is required to recover from 15% bad bits, that's ok, I can add more

@nneonneo I use C#, but I can work with C, Java, JS or Python too.

@PanJanek - that 15% bad bit rate also applies to the parity bits added, which requires a lot of parity bits. If using BCH code, GF(2^6): x^6 + x + 1, 63 bits, 15% is 9.45 bits, so 10 bit error correction is needed, which is 13 bits of data, 50 bits of parity. You'd need 3 of these (192) bits for 32 bits of data, or up to 39 bits of data.

@rcgldr BCH looks promising because , as i understand, they can be adjusted to any number of data bits and required error corrections count. Which one to use for 32bits of data and requirement to be able to correct 5 error bits? What about 28bits of data? Or 24bits?

Slide 8 of this presentation gives a full list of all the non-trivial binary BCH codes: https://web.ntpu.edu.tw/~yshan/BCH_code.pdf. For 36 bits of data, the code of length 63 with k=36 and t=5 will suffice (27 check bits). This requires transmitting 59 bits. You can just transmit fewer bits for less data (e.g. transmitting 55 or 51 bits), or pick e.g. 63/30/6 or 63/24/7 for increased error tolerance.

@PanJanek - I had commented about the 5 bit case before, but deleted it since you mentioned 8. nneonneo is correct, 36 bits data, 27 parity bits if using GF(2^6): x^6 + x + 1.  I'll post code in an answer.
