What error correcting code to use for short messages over noisy channel using confidence info for each bit (possible with transmission markers)
I have short (assume 24 to 30 bit long) message to send over a noisy channel. Additionally, the channel allows only sending 0 or 1, without "silence", so start transmission marker is needed. For each bit I receive I have confidence from 0.0 (we don't know which bit was sent at all) to 1.0 (we are certain that given bit was sent) - this can be easily translated to different range like: -127 (ceraint '0') ... 0 (no idea what was sent) ... 127 (certain 1).
For now I used this excelent answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/79145998/207717
to my previous question, together with some naive start-transmission markers to get fairly good results, but I don't use confidence values for received bits nor anything advanced for start-transmission-markers, so I'm sure that can be improved.
I've read about some advanced error correcting codes, used in wireless communication, 5G and space missions like:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_code
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Golay_code
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Muller_code

But this quickly turns into a deep rabbit hole with very advanced math. I would expect some libraries implementing these solutions that are not patented, but I cannot find anything above CRC, Reed Solomon and some BCH.
Could you recommend best practical approach?
Computational performance is not important, simple, reference, implementation in python would be enough.

Turbo codes use an analog component for the confidence factor, is the voltage | frequency | ... clearly a 1 or 0 or somewhere in between. Another scheme that does this along with rules for encoding data is PRML, used for magnetic media. Audio modems use Trellis encoding, a 4D computer generated mapping table. You don't mention if the channel is analog or digital (only two clearly distinguishable states for 0 or 1).

@rcgldr when using 8|10 code, is there any clever way to detect (or recover) error in illegal transmission marker? As I see it, 1bit error in transmission marker change it so it will be interpreted as part of a message and other way - 1bit error in legal 10bit sometimes produce transmission marker - in both cases entire message is lost, and receiver has to wait entire mesage length for another try.

Since the 4 bit correction + 7 bit detection method uses 30 bits of data, you could use a (15,11) BCH | CRC code, 11 bits of data, 4 bits of parity, either x^4 + x + 1 (hex 13) or x^4 + x^3 + 1 (hex 19), plus a separate even parity bit to to end up with a (16,11) code. The 11 bits of data would be 0x000 to 0x0FF for data, and 0x555 for marker.
This code can do single bit correction + double bit detection. If there are 3 error bits, then the single bit correction could fail and produce a 4th bad bit. The unknown is the bit error rate. If most of the errors are single bit errors, those get fixed.
You could continue to use the 30 bit data + 33 bits parity correction I posted before, but since the (16,11) code produces 10 bit data values, you could switch to a Reed Solomon code that operates on 10 bit elements, using a (16,12) or (16,10) code.
Example C# code. Since this is single bit correction, a CRC type method can be used for correction for the 15 bit part. A CRC is generated for the received 15 bits, then cycled backwards, setting a bit to xor if or when the backwards cycled CRC == 0x08.
//      bchq16.cs         16bit codeword, GF(2^4) + parity
//                        correct 1 bit, detect 2 bits
//                        2024NOV14 15:00

using System.Runtime.Intrinsics;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86;
using System.Numerics;

namespace xcs
{
    public class Program
    {
        const byte POLY = 0x13;                     // GF(2^4) = x^4 + x + 1
        const byte ALPHA = 0x02;
        static Vector128<ulong> poly;               // generator poly
        static Vector128<ulong> invpoly;            // 2^64 / POLY
        static Vector128<ulong> msg;                // message
        static Vector128<ulong> rem;                // remainder
        static Vector128<ulong> ren;                // reencode
        static ulong msgorg;                        // original message
        static ulong msgenc;                        // encoded message
        static ulong msgerr;                        // received message
        static ulong msgfix;                        // fixed message
        static ulong msgpar;                        // parity

        static void GenPoly()
        {
        ulong M;
        ulong N;
        ulong Q;
        int x;
        byte i;
            poly = Vector128.Create((ulong)POLY, 0x0000000000000000ul);
            // generate 2^64 / poly
            x = 63-BitOperations.LeadingZeroCount(poly.GetElement(0));
            M = 1ul<<x;
            N = M>>1;
            Q = 0x0ul;
            for(i = 0; i < 65-x; i++){
                N <<= 1;
                Q <<= 1;
                if(0 != (N&M)){
                    Q |= 1;
                    N ^= (poly.GetElement(0));
                }
            }
            invpoly = Vector128.Create(Q, 0x0000000000000000ul);
        }

        static void Encode()
        {
            Remainder();                                            // generate remainder
            msg ^= rem;                                             // msg[0] = encoded message
        }

        static void Remainder()
        {
            rem = Pclmulqdq.CarrylessMultiply(msg, invpoly, 0x00);  // rem[1] = quotient
            rem = Pclmulqdq.CarrylessMultiply(rem, poly, 0x01);     // rem[0] = product
            rem ^= msg;                                             // rem[0] = remainder
        }

        static void FixError()
        {
        ulong crc;
        ulong fix = 0;
        byte i;
            /* reencode crc */
#if false
            crc = msg.GetElement(0);
            for (i = 0; i < 15; i++){
                crc <<= 1;
                if(0x0ul != (crc & 0x8000ul))
                    crc ^= POLY<<11;
            }
            crc >>= 11;
#else
            ren = Vector128.Create(msg.GetElement(0)<<4, 0x0000000000000000ul);
            rem = Pclmulqdq.CarrylessMultiply(ren, invpoly, 0x00);  // rem[1] = quotient
            rem = Pclmulqdq.CarrylessMultiply(rem, poly, 0x01);     // rem[0] = product
            rem ^= ren;                                             // rem[0] = reencode
            crc = rem.GetElement(0);
#endif

            /* reverse cycle crc, fix 0 or 1 error */
            for (i = 0; i < 15; i++){
                crc = (0x0ul != (crc&1))?(crc^POLY)>>1:(crc)>>1;
                if(crc == 0x0008ul)
                    fix ^= 1ul<<i;
            }
            fix ^= msg.GetElement(0);
            msg = Vector128.Create(fix, 0x0000000000000000ul);
        }

        static void InitCombination(ref int[] a, int k, int n)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                a[i] = i;
            --a[k - 1];
        }

        static int NextCombination(ref int[] a, int k, int n)
        {
            int pivot = k - 1;
            while (pivot >= 0 && a[pivot] == n - k + pivot)
                --pivot;
            if (pivot == -1)
                return 0;
            ++a[pivot];
            for (int i = pivot + 1; i < k; ++i)
                a[i] = a[pivot] + i - pivot;
            return 1;
        }

        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] ptn = new int[2];             // error bit indexes
            int n;                              // number of errors to test
            int i;
            GenPoly();
            msgorg = 0x0000000000005550ul;      // test message
            msg = Vector128.Create(msgorg, 0x0000000000000000ul);
            Encode();
            msgenc = msg.GetElement(0)<<1;
            msgenc ^= (ulong)(BitOperations.PopCount(msgenc)&1);
            for (n = 1; n <= 2; n++){           // test 1 to 2 bit error patterns
                InitCombination(ref ptn, n, 16);
                while (0 != NextCombination(ref ptn, n, 16)){
                    msgerr = msgenc;
                    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                        msgerr ^= 1ul<<ptn[i];
                    msgpar = (ulong)(BitOperations.PopCount(msgerr)&1);
                    msgerr >>= 1;
                    msg = Vector128.Create(msgerr, 0x0000000000000000ul);
                    msgfix = msgerr;
                    Remainder();                // generate remainder
                    if(0ul == rem.GetElement(0)){ // if rmndr == 0
                        msgfix <<= 1;           // regenerate parity bit
                        msgfix ^= (ulong)(BitOperations.PopCount(msgfix)&1);
                        if(msgfix != msgenc){   // check for failure
                            Console.WriteLine("failed");
                            return 0;}
                        continue;
                    }
                    if(msgpar == 0ul)           // if error but even parity
                        continue;               //   detected error
                    FixError();                 // assume 1 bit error
                    msgfix = msg.GetElement(0);
                    if(msgfix == msgerr)        // if not 1 bit error
                        continue;               //  detected error
                    msgfix <<= 1;               // regenerate parity bit
                    msgfix ^= (ulong)(BitOperations.PopCount(msgfix)&1);
                    if(msgfix != msgenc){       // check for fixed
                        Console.WriteLine("failed");
                        return 0;}
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("passed");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

CRC(24,11), 13 bit CRC, fix 2 bit + detect 5 bit or fix 3 bit + detect 4 bit. Both 12 bit and 13 bit CRC have Hamming distance 8 for 11 data bits, 13 bit CRC used so codeword is 24 bits instead of 23 bits.
//      crc24.cs          24 bit codeword, 11 bit data, 13 bit crc
//                        2024NOV20 18:00

using System.Runtime.Intrinsics;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86;
using System.Numerics;

namespace xcs
{
    public class Program
    {
#if true
        const  uint  FIX = 2;                   // fix 2
        const  uint  DET = 5;                   // detect 5
#else
        const  uint  FIX = 3;                   // fix 3
        const  uint  DET = 4;                   // detect 4
#endif
#if true
        const  ulong POLY = 0x216F;             // AE3*3*3
#else
        const  ulong POLY = 0x3DA1;             // C75*3*3
#endif
        static uint[] fixtbl = new uint[8192];  // fix table
        static Vector128<ulong> poly;           // generator poly
        static Vector128<ulong> invpoly;        // 2^64 / POLY
        static Vector128<ulong> msg;            // message
        static Vector128<ulong> par;            // parities
        static ulong msgorg;                    // original message
        static ulong msgenc;                    // encoded message
        static ulong msgerr;                    // received message
        static ulong msgfix;                    // fixed message

        static void GenPoly()
        {
        int[] ptn = new int[8];                 // error bit indexes
        ulong M;
        ulong N;
        ulong Q;
        int i;
        int n;
        int x;
            poly = Vector128.Create(POLY, 0ul);
            // generate 2^64 / poly
            x = 63-BitOperations.LeadingZeroCount(poly.GetElement(0));
            M = 1ul<<x;
            N = M>>1;
            Q = 0x0ul;
            for(i = 0; i < 65-x; i++){
                N <<= 1;
                Q <<= 1;
                if(0 != (N&M)){
                    Q |= 1;
                    N ^= (poly.GetElement(0));
                }
            }
            invpoly = Vector128.Create(Q, 0ul);
            // init fix table
            fixtbl[0] = 0;
            for(i = 1; i < 8192; i++)
                fixtbl[i] = 0xffffffffu;
            for(n = 1; n <= FIX; n++)
            {           // fix 1 to FIX bit error
                InitCombination(ref ptn, n, 24);
                while(0 != NextCombination(ref ptn, n, 24))
                {
                    msgfix = 0ul;
                    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
                        msgfix ^= 1ul << ptn[i];
                    msg = Vector128.Create(msgfix, 0ul);
                    par = Pclmulqdq.CarrylessMultiply(msg, invpoly, 0x00);  // par[1] = quotient
                    par = Pclmulqdq.CarrylessMultiply(par, poly, 0x01);     // par[0] = product
                    par ^= msg;                                             // par[0] = crc
                    fixtbl[par.GetElement(0)] = (uint)msgfix;
                }
            }
        }

        static void Encode()
        {
            Remainder();                                            // generate remainder
            msg ^= par;                                             // msg[0] = encoded message
        }

        static void Remainder()
        {
            par = Pclmulqdq.CarrylessMultiply(msg, invpoly, 0x00);  // par[1] = quotient
            par = Pclmulqdq.CarrylessMultiply(par, poly, 0x01);     // par[0] = product
            par ^= msg;                                             // par[0] = crc
        }

        static bool FixError()
        {
            par = Pclmulqdq.CarrylessMultiply(msg, invpoly, 0x00);  // par[1] = quotient
            par = Pclmulqdq.CarrylessMultiply(par, poly, 0x01);     // par[0] = product
            par ^= msg;                                             // par[0] = crc
            par = Vector128.Create(fixtbl[par.GetElement(0)],0ul);  // par[0] = fix pattern
            if(par.GetElement(0) == 0xfffffffful)
                return false;
            msg ^= par;
            return true;
        }

        static void InitCombination(ref int[] a, int k, int n)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                a[i] = i;
            --a[k - 1];
        }

        static int NextCombination(ref int[] a, int k, int n)
        {
            int pivot = k - 1;
            while(pivot >= 0 && a[pivot] == n - k + pivot)
                --pivot;
            if(pivot == -1)
                return 0;
            ++a[pivot];
            for(int i = pivot + 1; i < k; ++i)
                a[i] = a[pivot] + i - pivot;
            return 1;
        }

        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] ptn = new int[8];             // error bit indexes
            int n;                              // number of errors to test
            int i;
            GenPoly();
            msgorg = 0x0000000000ffe000ul;      // test message
            msg = Vector128.Create(msgorg, 0ul);
            Encode();
            msgenc = msg.GetElement(0);
            for(n = 1; n <= DET; n++){         // test 1 to DET bit error patterns
                InitCombination(ref ptn, n, 24);
                while(0 != NextCombination(ref ptn, n, 24)){
                    msgerr = msgenc;
                    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
                        msgerr ^= 1ul<<ptn[i];
                    msg = Vector128.Create(msgerr, 0ul);
                    msgfix = msgerr;
                    if(!FixError())             // if not correctable
                        continue;               //  continue
                    msgfix = msg.GetElement(0);
                    if(msgfix != msgenc){
                        Console.WriteLine("failed");
                        return 0;}
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("passed");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}


Splitting my 30bit data into chunks of 10bits and using additional bit of (16,11) code for marker is a great idea! But I still I don't know how to detect the marker (or any other 16bit packet) on the reiceiver side. The receiver will be given some sample of the received bits, for example 100bits. The hardest part now is to identify the offset in these 100bits (between 0-15, because data will be send all the time) where is the start of 16bit of (16,11) codeword. Assuming that there can be an error in each (16,11) codeword simple  search for substring probably won't work.

The comunication channel is quite specific and we can assume that the clocks are synchronized. Receiveng part produce stream of bits. The length of the message (data+parity+marker) is fixed - call it N bits. After the message is sent, the sender sends it again and again. So after receiveing N bits I'd like to try to decode the data as I have all the bits, but shifted (rotated) by unknown offset. If too many errors are detected, I'll wait for another N bits. I don't know how to find the offset. Adding some  constant marker like 0x555 work only if there is 0 errors in the marker part.

I tested replacing 555 marker with CRC10 of entire 30bit message for 4x CRC(16,11) scheme and it works much better in terms of avoiding decoding the data incorrectly. Still, sometimes the marker is not detected correctly (if two errors happen in the marker 16bit part it is incorrectly recognized. Then the rest of the message is garbage, so CRC(16,11) decodes it incorrectly quite often and then the CRC10 fails to detect such error in about 0.02% cases). I plan to use two markers to further decrease probability of such cases.

@PanJanek - I updated my answer with CRC(24,11) (13 bit CRC) code, HD = 8. Can fix 2 + detect 5 or fix 3 + detect 4. That should help with detecting marker. The codeword would start off with the first 24 bits of received data, checked to see if a marker, and if not, cycle received bits one at a time into the 24 bit test code until you get a marker.

@PanJanek - any progress on this?

Yes, I get successfull decodings but it turned out that the clocks are not synchronized, so I have some problems sampling the channel in correct intervals. I receive array of samples, around 60 (but not exact) samples per bit (each sample is 0 or 1). Each sample can be corrupted. I use simple algorith to convert this stream of samples into stream of bits. It work, but the detection rate is not good enough. I'm thinking about some encoding scheme that would allow to synchronize better. The entire codeword is 92 bits now and during transmitting one codeword, the clock may shift up to 2 bits.

@PanJanek - I was wondering about synchronized clocks. Are you using something like GetElapsedTime() (stopwatch) to get accurate timing? When sampling bits at 60 samples per bit, for the first bit of a codeword, wait until something like 45 to 50 of 60 samples are the same to consider it as the starting bit boundary. When sampling set counter = 0, increment when bit == 1, decrement when bit == 0, wait until counter = +|- 45 to 50, then continue for another 10 samples to get to the second bit boundary. Keep using this counter for the remaining bits, as a 2 bit drift won't mess up the count.

@PanJanek - I'm thinking you should use the (24,11) code, since it can fix 2 + detect 5 or fix 3 + detect 4. If that isn't enough, you may need to use some type of RLL code, that guarantees a bit change every few bits.

After some more experiments it seems that the samples/bit rate is constant in one transmission (by transmission I mean codeword repeated several times), it may vary from 55-65 between transmissions but it is easy to detect, so RLL code is not required. After detecting correct samples/bit rate I get quite good decodings with (23,12) code repeated 4 times (1x23 marker containing CRC10 of data bits and 3x23 for data). If 4 subsequent  23bits segments cannot be decoded then I try to use segments from another, repeated codeword. Thanks for (24,11) code, I'm going to use it in next iteration .

@PanJanek - (24,11) code should be a bit more convenient (byte boundary on transmitter side), more error correction and not a wasted data bit as with (23,12) code.

Yes, I tested (24,11) and, as expected, it performs better Additionally, if some fragment is undecodable I use further fragments to combine entire message. This works well. Now I'm thinking about another encoding scheme for even more noise, like 25% error rate. I was thinking about splitting my 30bit (and internal crc10 in marker part) data into smaller chunks adding one marker bit as before and using some CRC codes like (23,5)HD=13, (15,5)HD=6, (11,3)HD=6 or even (15,2)HD=10 but then the combined codeword is geting long (>200bits). Are there better approaches for such error rates?

@PanJanek - at some point the error rate becomes too high for a correcting code or run length limited code to handle.  Consider any code where only 8 good bits are needed, with an error rate of 0.25, the probability of a good bit is 0.75 and the probability of 8 good bits is 0.75^8  ~= 10%.
